# How to do the equivalent of T[Any] for higher kinded types in scala

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

context: this is using scala-3

```scala
final case class TableSchema[T[_[_]] <: Table]( /* ... */ )
```

```
// None of these work...
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[TableSchema[_ <: Table]])
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[[t[_[_]] <: Table] => TableSchema[t]])
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[[t[_[_]] <: Table] =>> TableSchema[t]])
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[TableSchema[_[_[_]] <: Table]]) // isnt even valid syntax?
```

Comment: Why not just `final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[TableSchema[?]])` if you donot care about the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, correct is

```
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[TableSchema[_ <: ([_[_]] =>> Table)]])
```

or without extra brackets

```
final case class Schema(tableSchemas: List[TableSchema[_ <: [_[_]] =>> Table]])
```

i.e. unknown argument `_` of existential type `TableSchema[_]` is a subtype of the constant type `Table`.

A quote from [Type Lambdas - More Details / Relationship with Parameterized Type Definitions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html#relationship-with-parameterized-type-definitions):

> A parameterized abstract type
>
> `type T[X] >: L <: U`
>
> is regarded as shorthand for an unparameterized abstract type with
> type lambdas as bounds.
>
> `type T >: ([X] =>> L) <: ([X] =>> U)`

Tested in Scala 3.1.3.

Comment: This compiles for me, thank you so much!